# Problems with https routes

Tags: c#, azure, routes, webforms

I have two systems that talk to each other, one in mvc and the other in webforms.
I have ssl certificate, and when it's in mvc, it works on https, but when it goes to webforms, it loads https, and then reloads http.
So making my system not safe, I think it's some kind of route problem.I tried to force https, and anyway I do that, it goes into an infinite loop on these pages in webforms.

```
public class RouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
   
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (PageVirtualPath == string.Empty || PageVirtualPath == null || requestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("page"))
            PageVirtualPath = "~/" + requestContext.RouteData.Values["page"] + ".aspx";

        // Add the querystring to the URL in the current context
        if (!requestContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("email"))
        {
            string queryString = "?" + PageQueryString;
            if (queryString != "?")
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(string.Concat(PageVirtualPath, queryString));
        }
        Page page = null;
        try
        {
            page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(PageVirtualPath, typeof(Page)) as Page;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string erro = ex.ToString();
            page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/404.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
        }


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> key in requestContext.RouteData.Values)
            HttpContext.Current.Items[key.Key.Replace("*", "")] = key.Value;
        return page;
    }

    public string PageVirtualPath { get; set; }
    public string PageQueryString { get; set; }
}
```

And here's part of my `Global.aspx` code

```
 routes.Add("BillExpense",
            new Route("{BillExpense}/billexpensenew",
                null,
                null,
                new RouteHandler { PageVirtualPath = "~/BillExpense/billexpensenew.aspx" }));
```

How can I fix this, to work on https ?
Thanks guys right now, I'm messing with routes now, and because it's an old system, I'm in need of a lot of help.

**EDIT:**
This happens when I publish in azure, local is http, and works normally.

I really something that are these routes that are getting in the way, but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: check IIS for rewrite rules https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https and then possibly check for rewrite modules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check TLS version on working and non working apps.  Most likely the working is using TLS 1.2 or 1.3 and the non working is using TLS 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: @kshkarin The system is published on azure.

Comment: @jdweng I'll check.

Comment: When a HTTP/HTTPS connection is made there is a negotiation that is made between the client and server using the headers of the server webpage and the request from the client.  When a failure occurs retries can occur.  The HTTPS is failing initially on the IIS so a retry is make and finally HTTP is used.  THE HTTPS SSL/TLS is authentication is failing on IIS.  I assumed when you said SSL the actual authentication would be SSL.  SSL, TLS 1.0. and TLS 1.1 are not being used any more due to security issues.  So the IIS is refusing you SSL Certificate and need a new certificate for TLS 1.2/1.3.

Comment: @jdweng How can I solve this, can you help me? I've tried a lot of things, and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Did you use a sniffer and compare the SSL/TLS version in working mvc with the non working webform?  Also compare the headers in the first request between mvc and webform.  First get the SSL/TLS version the same and then the headers.